# How to create a BufferedImage from raw data

Tags: java, scala, awt, bufferedimage

I'm trying to get a BufferedImage from raw samples, but I get exceptions about trying to read past the available data range which I just don't understand. What I'm trying to do is:

```
val datasize = image.width * image.height
val imgbytes = image.data.getIntArray(0, datasize)
val datamodel = new SinglePixelPackedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, image.width, image.height, Array(image.red_mask.intValue, image.green_mask.intValue, image.blue_mask.intValue))
val buffer = datamodel.createDataBuffer
val raster = Raster.createRaster(datamodel, buffer, new Point(0,0))
datamodel.setPixels(0, 0, image.width, image.height, imgbytes, buffer)
val newimage = new BufferedImage(image.width, image.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
newimage.setData(raster)
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32784
    at java.awt.image.SinglePixelPackedSampleModel.setPixels(SinglePixelPackedSampleModel.java:689)
    at screenplayer.Main$.ximage_to_swt(Main.scala:40)
    at screenplayer.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at screenplayer.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

The data is standard RGB with 1 byte padding (so that 1 pixel == 4 bytes) and the image size is 1366x24 px.

---

I finally got the code to run with the suggestion below. The final code is:

```
val datasize = image.width * image.height
val imgbytes = image.data.getIntArray(0, datasize)

val raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, image.width, image.height, 3, 8, null)
raster.setDataElements(0, 0, image.width, image.height, imgbytes)

val newimage = new BufferedImage(image.width, image.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
newimage.setData(raster)
```

If it can be improved, I'm open to suggestions of course, but in general it works as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setPixels` assumes that the image data is *not* packed.  So it's looking for an input of length image.width*image.height*3, and running off the end of the array.

Here are three options for how to fix the problem.

(1) Unpack `imgbytes` so it is 3x longer, and do it the same way as above.

(2) Manually load the buffer from `imgbytes` instead of using `setPixels`:

```
var i=0
while (i < imgbytes.length) {
  buffer.setElem(i, imgbytes(i))
  i += 1
}
```

(3) Don't use `createDataBuffer`; if you already know that your data has the proper formatting you can create the appropriate buffer yourself (in this case, a `DataBufferInt`):

```
val buffer = new DataBufferInt(imgbytes, imgbytes.length)
```

(you may need to do `imgbytes.clone` if your original copy could get mutated by something else).

Comment: I tried those solutions, but either I get unrelated garbage, or a black screen. The data is correct if I look at the hex dump of it. Could you provide a short fragment that actually goes from imgbytes to BufferedImage? It would be really appreciated :)

Comment: If you can provide code that creates `image` in your example, sure.  Or if you don't care how the data comes in, I'll create an example that isn't from an image.

Comment: That's a custom object I get straight from Xorg. If you can do it with known `height`, `width` and an array of either 4 byte components (RGB order + 1byte padding), or single int (same format) per each pixel, I can figure out the rest. The part where I fail is probably the buffer<->raster interaction (I'm not even sure if both are needed). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok - I got it to work (code included in the question). Unless this can be made simpler somehow - feel free to correct :)

Comment: After two weeks of trying to find some sort of information like this, I'm very very happy to find this question.  Thanks for the question and answer!